# Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)

Tags: java

Задача:
На числовой прямой дан отрезок [3;8]. Требуется определить, принадлежит ли точка x данному отрезку. Во входном потоке в единственной строке записано вещественное число x заданное не более чем с шестью знаками после точки (−1000≤x≤1000). Выведите true, если точка x принадлежит данному отрезку, или false в противном случае.
Язык, очевидно из названия треда, Java.

Мой код:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        double x = in.nextInt();
        boolean b = (x>=3) && (x<=8);
                System.out.print(b);
        }
}
```

При введении x = 8.1 Эклипс выдаёт мне ошибку:

```
***Error***
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
        at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
        at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
        at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
        at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
        at program.main(program.java:6)
```

И что ему не нравится?

Answer (score 1):

У вас несовпадение типов -

```
double x = in.nextInt();
```

надо:

```
double x = in.nextDouble();
```

и вроде бы ввод через запятую - 8,1 в этом варианте, проверьте сами.